# how lazy init works in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new in spring framework. I wanted compulsion that when creating a particular object its data member must be initialized.  So best way is to initialize it with constructor.

```
@Service
class GenerationServiceFactory{

@Autowired
private MyModel model;

public GenerationServiceFactory(MyModel obj){
model = obj;
}

}
```

But actual model object is created at run time. Then how can i pass that object when spring create all beans. I know its related to lazy init. But i don't know how it works. Please help me.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

When using lazy initialisation, Spring will create objects upon demand. So if class A depends on class B, class B won't be instantiated until class A is requested. Spring will navigate the tree of dependencies and instantiate *as required*.

Answer (score 2):

If `lazy-init` bean is referenced from the singleton bean, it's created as a part of the singleton bean dependencies graph. You may work this around with a dynamic proxy like that:

```
 <bean id="first" class="package.TestBean1">
     <property name="field" ref="second"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="second" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
     <property name="targetSource">
          <bean class="org.springframework.aop.target.LazyInitTargetSource">
              <property name="targetBeanName" value="rawSecond"/>
          </bean>
     </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="rawSecond" class="package.TestBean2" lazy-init="true">
```

This configuration will delay `rawSecond` instantiation until the first method call is made.

Comment: In your example, what will be the sequence of initializing beans?

Comment: On context load TestBean1 will be instantiated. Next, a proxy bean will go, as TestBean1 requires dependency injection. TestBean2 will not be instantiated until TestBean1 invokes any of proxy bean methods. It may even happen, that TestBean2 will not be instantiated at all, if TestBean1 made no calls to TestBean2.

Comment: Oh great...thanks...Spring is amazing :) loving it :)

Comment: can u tell me how can i do this with annotations?

Comment: Try the following annotation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally in spring framework when spring container loads the XML config file 
all the beans will be initiated at once. Suppose there comes a situation in your application where you do not want some beans to initialise as soon as the XML is loaded in container or in other word you want it to load it at runtime, in that case you can give the attribute lazy-init="true".

You can check here for sample [example](http://www.javavni.com/lazy-init--spring-bean-attributes-.html)